# How to sort an array in to group of 3 elements in groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm new to groovy scripting and trying to sort below array where sorting is happening as group of three elements.

> I/p: a = [9, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 3]
>   Expected O/P: 4,5,9, 7,8,9, 2,3,4

I tried many combinations however I my loop is either going into an infinite loop or I can sort only first group of three elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++) {    
    for (int j = i + 1; j<3; j++) {    
        if (a[i] > a[j]) `enter code here`
        {
            temp = [0]
            temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[j]
            a[j] = temp
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++) {
    log.info a[i]+ ","
}
log.info "Data in ascending order" + a
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use bubble sort, but not in the right way.

First problem is (a[i] > a[j]) , here i is constant, in bubble sort we use here j and j+1, because we compare 2 consecutive elements. if we keep i here then i is constant inside the loop

first group of elements are getting sorted for you because the first 3 elements are 9 4 5 because 9>4 so you swapped and again 9>5 so swapping was done so they got swapped

Another thing for bubble sort is we need 2 loops for sorting. in one go only adjacent elements gets sorted. i.e. suppose elements are 3 2 1. so it will be like 2 3 1 (2,3) , and then 2 1 3 (1,3). u need 1 more iteration(outer loop) to make it 1 2 3 .

So below is the bubble sort logic which uses the same logic as yours and gives the output you need without using any special methods available

I tried to figure out the infinite logic but not able to crack that one...

Below code works in the simplest way https://ideone.com/B9fY0A

1) First loop is 2 break elements into set of 3... so we pick 1 4 8 element

2) Third loop starts with element decided by first loop

3) Second loop is to take care of sorting happens for 3 elements(bubble sort needs 2 loops)

```
def a = [9, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 3] ;
def temp=0;
print "ok";
for(int i =0; i <a.size(); i=i+3)
{
print a[i] + " "
for(int k=0; k<2;k++)
{
for(int j=i;j<i+2;j++)
{
//  print a
    if(a[j]>a[j+1])
    {
        temp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[j+1];
        a[j+1]=temp;

    }
}
}
}

log.info a
```

This is following the logic you mentioned or your way we can say

Answer (score 3):

Groovy is very powerful for this kind of tasks:

```
def a = [9, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 3]
def sorted = a.collate( 3 ).collect{it.sort()} 
assert sorted == [[4, 5, 9], [7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4]]
assert sorted.flatten() == [4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. But we are supposrd to do it without sort method.

Comment: Why? Ok, what about: a.collate( 3 ).collect{[it.min(), it - it.min() - it.max(), it.max()].flatten()} ?

Comment: @cfrick, yes..but mine is going into infinite loop when i use i+3 :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. It is not the *Grooviest* code, but it is both simple and reasonably close to the original. The main technique is to use a [range](http://grails.asia/groovy-range-examples) with a step (so that `i` goes from 0,3,6):

```
def a = [9, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 3] 
def n = a.size() - 1
assert a.size() % 3 == 0

def result = []

// i = 0, 3, 6 
for (i in (0..n).step(3)) {
    def list = [a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2]]
    def x = list.min()
    def z = list.max()
    def y = list.find { item -> item != x && item != z }
    result.addAll([x, y, z])
}

assert [4,5,9,7,8,9,2,3,4] == result
```